# How to push selected users in search div box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some users list and one search input box. When I choose users, the selected users have to pushed into search input box like in gmail, we enter To mail id, once we entered the mail-id will show within same input box in left. How can I implement that in javascript.

Comment: Please provide some code to work with so other people can try to reproduce it to help you. Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example